# Why am I unable to web-scrape URL from a hyperlink in this website?

Tags: python, url, web-scraping

I tried to extract URL from a hyperlink in this web: https://riwayat-file-covid-19-dki-jakarta-jakartagis.hub.arcgis.com/

I used the following Python code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://riwayat-file-covid-19-dki-jakarta-jakartagis.hub.arcgis.com/"
req = requests.get(url, headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())

links = soup.find_all('a')

for link in links:
    if "href" in link.attrs:
        print(str(link.attrs['href'])+"\n")
```

The problem is this code does not return any URL.

I want to get all of this urls:
[image: I want to get all of this urls]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are unable to parse it as the data is dynamically loaded. As you can see in the following image, the HTML data that is being written to the page doesn't actually exist when you download the HTML source code. The JavaScript later parses the `window.__SITE` variable and extracts the data from there:

[image: code screenshot]

However, we can replicate this in Python. After downloading the page:

```py
import requests

url = "https://riwayat-file-covid-19-dki-jakarta-jakartagis.hub.arcgis.com/"
req = requests.get(url)
```

You can use `re` (regex) to extract the encoded page source:

```py
import re

encoded_data = re.search("window\.__SITE=\"(.*)\"", req.text).groups()[0]
```

Afterwards, you can use `urllib` to URL-decode the text, and `json` to parse the JSON string data:

```py
from urllib.parse import unquote
from json import loads

json_data = loads(unquote(encoded_data))
```

You can then parse the JSON tree to get to the HTML source data:

```py
html_src = json_data["site"]["data"]["values"]["layout"]["sections"][1]["rows"][0]["cards"][0]["component"]["settings"]["markdown"]
```

At that point, you can use your own code to parse the HTML:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_src, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())

links = soup.find_all('a')

for link in links:
    if "href" in link.attrs:
        print(str(link.attrs['href'])+"\n")
```

If you put it all together, here's the final script:

```py
import requests
import re
from urllib.parse import unquote
from json import loads
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Download URL
url = "https://riwayat-file-covid-19-dki-jakarta-jakartagis.hub.arcgis.com/"
req = requests.get(url)

# Get encoded JSON from HTML source
encoded_data = re.search("window\.__SITE=\"(.*)\"", req.text).groups()[0]

# Decode and load as dictionary
json_data = loads(unquote(encoded_data))

# Get the HTML source code for the links
html_src = json_data["site"]["data"]["values"]["layout"]["sections"][1]["rows"][0]["cards"][0]["component"]["settings"]["markdown"]

# Parse it using BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_src, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())

# Get links
links = soup.find_all('a')

# For each link...
for link in links:
    if "href" in link.attrs:
        print(str(link.attrs['href'])+"\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

The links are generated dynamically by javascript code and the data can be found un the structure below.

```
<script id="site-injection">
      window.__SITE="your data is here"
</script>
```

So you need to grab this `script` element and parse the value of `window.__SITE`